# Rails 4: Show SQL in console in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

After upgrading to rails 4 the executed SQL is no longer shown when I execute commands in the rails console on my server in production. How can I enable that again, without hurting the performance?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

```
ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
```

Execute it in rails console on your server, and then all the ActiveRecord generated SQL queries will be shown.

Comment: Is there a way to do this "automatically" when the console starts up?

Comment: ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT) if defined? Rails::Console



#Put this line in application.rb or in specific environment file under environments directory.