# Rails `find_by` returning huge ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Curious if anyone knows the intricacies of `find_by` since I've checked documentation and been unable to find info.

I know that `find` is used to find by primary keys like:
`@user = User.find(params[:id])`, returning the correct user.

Before I corrected my code it was `@user = User.find_by(params[:id])` and returned a user with an ID way above the number of users in my DB.

Can anyone help me understand what is happening under the hood? What does find_by search by default when a parameter is omitted that is returning this strange user object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`find_by_field(value)` is equivalent to `where(field: value)` but is not supposed to be used without appending a field name to the method like you mentioned. Moreover it returns only the first matching value. For example instead of doing `User.where(name: 'John').limit(1)` you can use: `User.find_by_name 'John'`.

On my side, using `find_by` with postgresql raises an error, when `find_by_id` does work:

```
User.find_by(1)
SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE (1)  ORDER BY "users"."email" ASC LIMIT 1
PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR:  argument of WHERE must be type boolean, not type integer

User.find_by_id 1
SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 1  ORDER BY "users"."email" ASC LIMIT 1
<User id: 1, ...

User.where(id: 1) # note that there is no LIMIT 1 in the generated SQL
SELECT "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 1  ORDER BY "users"."email" ASC
```

You can use gem [query_tracer](https://github.com/e1senh0rn/query_tracer) to see the generated SQL or check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20400352/rails-4-show-sql-in-console-in-production).

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html).

Here is an excerpt for find_by:

> Finds the first record matching the specified conditions. There is no implied ordering so if order matters, you should specify it yourself.
>
> If no record is found, returns nil.

```
Post.find_by name: 'Spartacus', rating: 4
Post.find_by "published_at < ?", 2.weeks.ago
```

Is that what you were looking for?

---

UPDATE

`User.find_by(3)` is [equivalent](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/f52354ad1d15120dcc5284714bee7ee3f052986c/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb#L83) to `User.where(3).take`
Here's the output from the console

```
pry(main)> User.where(3).take
#=>  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE (3) LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the lightening response but not quite. 

Specific to my app, params[:id] = 3 so `User.find(3)` find the correct user (3). 

However, `User.find_by(3)` returns a user with id 409608538 (way more than the 100 seed users I have) so I was just curious how that was happening

Comment: try User.find_by( id: 3) . What is the result?

Comment: btw, I can not replicate what you mention in the console; User.find(3), User.find_by(3), User.find_by(id: 3) all return the same, correct user. Can you include in your question some copy-paste from the console?

Comment: Interesting, when I run a sandbox console and use `User.find_by(id: 3)` we get the correct user (as expected), however when I put `User.find_by(ANY INTEGER)` it returns the first user in the DB. Where I was having the quirk was in the named route. When using user_path(User.find_by(3)) I get the weird user path of `/user/409608538` which I don't understand.

Comment: anyway, the correct way to use find_by would be to pass a condition, not an integer. Please see here: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/f52354ad1d15120dcc5284714bee7ee3f052986c/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb#L83

Comment: What SQL is being generated?

Comment: I will add to the answer, it is ugly in the comment

Comment: Sorry, I meant that for Splice114

Answer (score 0):

It's look like rails return to you an id of object in memory. It's like query `User.find(params[:id]).object_id`. But why it's happens? I try did same on my app with 4.2.4 version and all goes fine